# OkHttp and UTF-8 character encoding

Tags: java, android, utf-8, character-encoding, okhttp

I have a question about OkHttp in Android and its support for character encoding, specifically using UTF-8 to support swedish characters å, ä and ö (and capitals ÅÄÖ).

The app we are building uses OkHttp to make GET and POST calls to our server system. The server runs on Tomcat behind Apache. Both Apache and Tomcat are configured to use UTF-8 character coding by default. I assume what's needed is that the http requests sent from the Android app to the server are equipped with a header containing something like "application/text; charset=utf-8".

I built this stripped-down code example to illustrate the issue. As you can see, i have included addHeader() on the request to set a header. I have also actively set a Charset on the RequestBody.

```
public static String testPost() throws IOException{
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    HttpUrl.Builder builder = new HttpUrl.Builder();
    HttpUrl httpUrl = builder.scheme("https")
                             .host("dev.ourdomainname.com")
                             .addPathSegment("characterencoding")
                             .build();
    Charset charset = Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder(charset)
                                          .add("text", "xxåäöÅÄÖxx")
                                          .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(httpUrl)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    return "test completed";
}
```

At the server end, i am logging the value of the parameter named text, which comes in as "xxÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã?Ã?Ã?xx", which of course is not good enough. I also have code that loops over all headers in the request and logs them. The output looks like below. Notice how there is no "application/text; charset=utf-8" header.

```
DEBUG 23 Jan 14:52:37.128 - testCharacterEncoding. text: xxÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã?Ã?Ã?xx
DEBUG 23 Jan 14:52:37.129 - Header: content-type with value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DEBUG 23 Jan 14:52:37.129 - Header: content-length with value: 45
DEBUG 23 Jan 14:52:37.129 - Header: host with value: dev.cqrify.com
DEBUG 23 Jan 14:52:37.129 - Header: connection with value: Keep-Alive
DEBUG 23 Jan 14:52:37.129 - Header: accept-encoding with value: gzip
DEBUG 23 Jan 14:52:37.129 - Header: user-agent with value: okhttp/3.9.1
```

So my question is: are we doing this the wrong way? If yes, what is the right way to do it? Worst case, this could be a bug in OkHttp, but i doubt it.

For comparison, i built a simple html form to make the exact same post, and the same string sent that way comes in as "xxåäöÅÄÖxx", which is correct.

Comment: `.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")` does not match with `Header: content-type with value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Please elaborate,

Comment: Well greenapps, that seems to be the epicenter of the problem. The request comes across with a different Content-type than the one i have added.

Comment: @greenapps, I had upvoted your comment but then realized what what Mats was showing - the log entry is from when he tried his form post with a simple html page.  Mats - could it be that your java code, e.g. `.add("text", "xxåäöÅÄÖxx")` is not ending up being compiled properly - possibly the encoding is not supported?  You might try doing a System.out.println of that and see if it does print out okay - maybe this github [example](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) might help?

Comment: No the logging code is from the receiving server code when the call from the app comes in.

Comment: Tried your code and it works ok for me. I just let a php script return the text and it comes back ok. Using okhttp-3.4.1. Omitting the charset as the FormBody constructor does not have that parameter.

Comment: So in your incoming request, greenapps, do you see the "Content-Type: application/text; charset=utf-8" header? I suspect that the fact that it is not added to the request in my case is the source of this issue.

Comment: I dont know. I did not look there.

Comment: Some additional info on this. Using the code below, i'm logging the headers of the okhttp request:

Comment: `Set<String> headerNames = request.headers().names();
        for(String headerName : headerNames) {
            Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Header: " + headerName + " : " + request.headers().get(headerName));
        }`

Comment: This  logs one single line: `Header: Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Using mod_forensics in Apache, i can see the incoming message and its headers. For some reason, the one set up is not there: `+8224:5a6b0869:0|POST /restfulservice/test/characterencoding/post HTTP/1.1|Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded|Content-Length:45|Host:dev.mydomainname.com|Connection:Keep-Alive|Accept-Encoding:gzip|User-Agent:okhttp/3.9.1
-8224:5a6b0869:0
`

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two different problems here.

**1. Your Content-type header is (correctly) ignored**

The Content-type header that you set is being overriden when you later call `.post(requestBody)` on your `request` object. This is because you are using a `FormBuilder` object to build your POST body, and this is specifically meant to be used for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` forms. If you want to post JSON data, you should not be using this. Instead, try this:

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
[...]
```

Here's the [full source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/guide/PostExample.java) from the official OkHttp examples.

**2. Non-ASCII characters are garbled**

Even if you stick with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, non ASCII text should work fine. So what is happening in your case?

I suspect an encoding problem when you compile your source code; i.e. charset used by javac does not match charset of your Java source file. You may want to explicitly pass `-encoding utf8` (or whatever encoding you are using in your source files) to javac, or even better, avoid any non-ASCII characters in your source code and use Unicode escapes instead. In this case, instead of `xxåäöÅÄÖxx`, you may want to use `xx\u00E5\u00E4\u00F6\u00C5\u00C4\u00D6xx`

Comment: Hello Grodriguez and thank you for your reply. It's been quite a while since i posted this and i realize i should close it and sharqe the solution.